# Type conversions on values within a list where there are empty strings

Tags: python, list

```
array = [{'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 00:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'CO',
          '@Value': '0.3'},
         {'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 01:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'CO',
          '@Value': '0.3'}....}]

try:
    pm10 = [float(d['@Value']) for d in array if d['@SpeciesCode'] == 'PM10']
except ValueError:
    pm10 = [''] * 24
```

I am using data from a JSON API for plotting in highcharts and so I need to convert the values from strings into floats. The problem is that there are occasional missing values where there is just an empty string. This causes a ValueError, which is why I need the try/except block.

Where there are only just a few missing values, currently the whole set of data will need to replaced (using the except clause), in order to avoid a ValueError for the float conversion.

So for a list such as this:

```
['3.4', '', '4.0']
```

I need to end up with a list like this:

```
[3.4, '', 4.0]
```

How can I make it so the float conversion is attempted just on those containing values and not on the empty strings?

Comment: Define a function `safe_float()` that attempts to convert an element of your list to a float and returns the numeric value if conversion is possible and `''`, otherwise. Apply this function to your list elements in the list comprehension expression instead of `float()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appends a empty str if `d['@Value']` is `""`

```
#adds d['@Value'] only if its a empty str
pm10 = [d['@Value'] if d['@Value'] == '' else float(d['@Value']) for d in array if d['@SpeciesCode'] == 'PM10']
```

for example:

```
array = [{'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 00:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'CO',
          '@Value': '0.3'},
         {'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 01:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'PM10',
          '@Value': '0.5'},
         {'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 01:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'PM10',
          '@Value': ''},
         {'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 01:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'PM10',
          '@Value': '3.5'}]


pm10 = [d['@Value'] if d['@Value'] == '' else float(d['@Value']) for d in array if '@SpeciesCode' in d.keys() if d['@SpeciesCode'] == 'PM10']
```

output will be:

```
[0.5, '', 3.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

> that there are occasional missing values where there is just an empty
>   string.

If I understood you correctly, the following simple condition should fit your requirement:

```
# the example was slightly modified to show empty strings proccessing
array = [{'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 00:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'PM10',
          '@Value': '0.3'},
         {'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 01:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'PM10',
          '@Value': ''},
         {'@MeasurementDateGMT': '2017-02-25 01:00:00',
          '@SpeciesCode': 'PM10',
          '@Value': '0.5'}]

pm10 = [float(d['@Value']) if d['@Value'].strip() else '' for d in array if d['@SpeciesCode'] == 'PM10']
print(pm10)
```

The output:

```
[0.3, '', 0.5]
```